# I have an errormessage in a localized ubuntu, how to get the english version of that message?

Tags: locale

Sometimes I get an errormessage that I want to ask about here, but the errormessages are in my locale language. Often this are not really reproducable, so that I cant switch to english and reproduce...

So how do I get the english version of that errormessage to ask a question about that problem here or can find answers?

Comment: If nothing else, post the raw error message here with the best translation of the non-technical words. You can see if there is a LOCO near you, or try the appropriate #ubuntu channel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I sometimes do is just paste the error-message in google +  use the search term "translate launchpad" or "translations launchpad".

Dutch example: "Weet u zeker dat u alle programma's wilt afsluiten en de computer wilt herstarten?"

[image: The dialog box]

Then Google: "Weet u zeker dat u alle programma's wilt afsluiten en de computer wilt herstarten? translate launchpad"

[image: Google the error]

Choose a page (this is sometimes a bit tricky), and with a bit of luck you get a page that looks like this:

[image: Profit!]

Hope this helps.

Note that this only works for programs that use launchpad for translations. But most Ubuntu programs do, so it's worth trying.

Answer (score 4):

You can run the program also from gnome-terminal with LANG=C in front of it, e.g. `LANG=C <program-name>`

Comment: I am aware of that fact, but as I told, that error might not be reproducable.